# How to call HSQLDB Function MONTHS_BETWEEN?

Tags: java, sql, function, hsqldb

I'm trying to execute the follow SQL:

`select months_between(sc.dat_initial_period, hp.dat_signup) + 1 as months
from 
    harvest_partner hp
inner join sales_commission sc
    on hp.idt_harvest_partner = sc.idt_harvest_partner;`

Against HSQLDB version: `2.2.9` and I'm receiving the follow error:

`Error code -5501, SQL state 42501: user lacks privilege or object not found: MONTHS_BETWEEN`

I'm creating database by this URL: `jdbc:hsqldb:/hsql/testdb`

The SQL is being executed by Netbeans SQL Client, by the HSQLDB Database Manager and even by a pure JDBC Java code, in all the error occurs.

The HSQLDB documentation says that it have such function (`MONTHS_BETWEEN`):
http://hsqldb.org/doc/2.0/guide/builtinfunctions-chapt.html#bfc_datetime_arithmetic

And in the follow link says that it was implemented is some snapshot's released in Nov/2012:
http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.java.hsqldb.user/6201

There is something wrong with my code or I'm missing any configuration to be able to call such function?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This function is supported by HSQLDB 2.3.0. You can get the latest snapshot here:

http://www.hsqldb.org/repos/org/hsqldb/hsqldb/SNAPSHOT/

Comment: Do you know when it will be released?